# How to send a sms from wifi

Tags: ios, sms, wifi

I am trying to develop an iOS app that involves sending SMS, but I would like it to work on an iPod touch also. How would I send the SMS over wifi, or are there any alternatives? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This isn't possible, SMS messaging uses the cellular network and even on iPhone, you don't have access to low-enough-level functions to send an SMS programatically, you can only display a view controller to have the user tap 'send'. iMessage works over data (cellular/wifi) but is subject to the same restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Evangelist here

The comment above is quite correct, but in terms of services that can help you, you could look at [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com). You could use Twilio to buy a telephone number for the iPod touch, then use a server to receive SMS messages and push them to the device to a custom SMS app. You could even add VOIP calling for voice too. Basically making it into a Voice/SMS capable device that works over Wifi.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I looked into that site before, but didn't really understand how the site works. I'll look into it.